# What are the evidence that gravitational force act across all spatial dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, branes

I keep hearing in the folk theory of physics that gravitational force (if a force it indeed is) will act across parallel universes or higher spatial dimensions.

Where did this idea come from? Does it have any scientific basis?

Comment: *Where* do you "keep hearing" this? I can guess what it *might* mean, but it's really rather difficult to tell what the correct answer to this question would be.

Answer (score 2):

Gravity works in all spatial dimensions. But all spatial dimensions are just our three D space. There are no other spatial dimensions as far as gravity is concerned.

The evidence of no other spatial dimensions (wrt gravity) is the inverse square law. Inverse square law would not hold good in more than three spatial dimensions. For example, in a 4 dimensional space, it would be a inverse cube law, not inverse square.

We have tendency to imagine weird things for justifying things we can not explain.

Comment: The inverse square law at large scale (for instance at the mm scale) does not exclude extra spatial dimensions. The extra spatial dimensions can exist as long as its scale is smaller than the scale at which the inverse square law has been tested.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the basic picture of Einstein's general relativity which says that gravity is the curvature of the spacetime. And a basic principle in physics is that every events happen in the spacetime. Whether or not our observable universe is embedded in a bigger spacetime, the gravity can not be localized on our universe only (note that, the gravitational waves may be localized).